# Animating Android Window along with the View

Tags: android, animation

I am doing a custom android build, in which my Service adds a View on top of every app. Using the following code:

```
WindowManager mWM = (WindowManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);WindowManager.LayoutParams mParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
mParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE, 
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL| WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, 
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
mParams.height = 117;
mParams.width = 366;
View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myView,null);
mWM.addView(myView, mParams);
```

I am able to add the view successfully. I am animating the view using

```
PropertyValuesHolder pvhX = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("x", 300);
ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(myView, pvhX).start();
```

I am seeing the view animate, but not the window. The transparent window where the view used to be, is not animating. This is same behavior as described in [Android Property Animation](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html)

> Another disadvantage of the view animation system is that it only modified where the View was drawn, and not the actual View itself. For instance, if you animated a button to move across the screen, the button draws correctly, but the actual location where you can click the button does not change, so you have to implement your own logic to handle this.

How do i animate the window along with the view?

Thanks

Comment: What does your `myView` layout look like?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options to achieve this (keeping the user's touch feedback coherent with the `View`'s position):

1. **Create a transparent container** (like a `FrameLayout`) big enough to contains your `View` plus its animation offset (in your case with an height of *366+300 px*). In this way, you will add the container to the `Window`, while the `View` stays inside the container and can be animated/traslated.
2. **Move the absolute position of your View on the screen**, creating a sort of custom animation; you just need to set the `mParams.x` value dynamically using a `ValueAnimator` or, if you want more bounciness, using a spring effect through the [Rebound](http://facebook.github.io/rebound/) library. I suggest you the last one, it's really fancy!

Here's an (untested) example using Rebound:

```
SpringSystem springSystem = SpringSystem.create();
Spring spring = springSystem.createSpring();
final int originalPos = mParams.x;
final int offset = 300;
spring.addListener(new SimpleSpringListener() {

  @Override
  public void onSpringUpdate(Spring spring) {
    float value = (float) spring.getCurrentValue(); 
    mParams.x = originalPos + ((int) value*offset)
    mWM.updateViewLayout(myView, mParams);
  }
});
spring.setEndValue(1);
```

Remember that you need to add the Rebound's compile statement in your dependencies first:

```
// Gradle dependency on Rebound
dependencies {
  compile 'com.facebook.rebound:rebound:0.3.8'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make it so that your window fills the entire screen by removing the height and width from the window params. If you want to control the view size, set it in your layout instead.

---

Otherwise, you can use a `ValueAnimator` and repeatedly call `WindowManager`'s `updateViewLayout`:

```
ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofInt(mParams.x, 300);
va.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        Integer value = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        mParams.x = value.intValue();
        mWM.updateViewLayout(myView, mParams);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this please:

```
WindowManager mWM = (WindowManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);WindowManager.LayoutParams mParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
mParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE, 
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL| WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, 
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
mParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
mParams.x = 0;
mParams.y = 0;

View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myView,null);
LinearLayout parent = new LinearLayout(context);
parent.addView(myView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
mWM.addView(parent, mParams);
```

And keep animate myView as you did

```
PropertyValuesHolder pvhX = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("x", 300);
ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(myView, pvhX).start();
```

Notice to
Set the width & height of the view in your XML file - R.layout.myView